# has_many :though with DISTINCT option won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tried the `distinct` option for has_many relationship

```
#user.rb
class User 
  has_many :badge_achievements
  has_many :badges, -> { uniq }, through: :badge_achievements
```

my test defines the following

```
#user_test.rb
user.badges.count.must_equal 1
# add the same badge again
user.badges << User::Badge.find(1)
user.badges.count.must_equal 1 #should not be changed
```

unfortunately it seems it's not validating correctly and therefore mysql is raising

`Error:
a user::has many community badges#test_0004_can have every badge only once:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '50-1' for key 'index_user_badge_achievements_on_user_id_and_badge_id': INSERT INTO`user_badge_achievements`(`user_id`,`badge_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (50, 1, '2016-12-12 02:17:56', '2016-12-12 02:17:56')
    test/models/user_test.rb:124:in`block (3 levels) in '`

do i have a misunderstanding on how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you don't have a uniqueness validation at all - your constraint only operates once you try to access the association after it has been saved in the database.

The error being thrown occurs before you get to that... it occurs because you have a uniqueness-constraint in the database itself that is (correctly) preventing the duplicate from being saved.

If you want to not get that error message, then you need an Active Record validation... something starting with the word `validates` - but then you can't test that count is equal to one - because it always will be (prevented at an earlier stage of the process).

Comment: so i need to validate badge_achievements? well, didn't thought about that. thanks

Comment: Yeah - i think that'll be your best shot at getting what you want :) Stop the bad data before it gets into the database, rather than confirming that it pulls it out in a uniquified way